# Set date value in time series based on value in previous row

Tags: r, dataframe, time, series

I have the following:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1:8), ref.date = c(NA, "10/12/18", NA, NA, "12/15/19", NA, NA, NA))
df$ref.date <- as.Date(df$ref.date, format = "%m/%d/%y")
df$new.date <- NA
```

I would like to update new.date such that for any given row, new.date is equal to ref.date if ref.date is not NA, and is equal to the value of new.date in the previous row if ref.date is NA. So the result would be:

```
A  ref.date new.date
1     <NA>       NA
2 10/12/18       10/12/18
3     <NA>       10/12/18
4     <NA>       10/12/18
5 12/15/19       12/15/19
6     <NA>       12/15/19
7     <NA>       12/15/19
8     <NA>       12/15/19
```

I tried

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(new.date = ifelse(is.na(ref.date), lag(new.date), ref.date))
df$new.date <- as.Date(df$new.date, format = "%m/%d/%y")
```

But this yielded dates in numeric format and did not fill rows correctly where ref.date is NA.

Comment: `df %>%
  mutate(new.date = ref.date) %>%
  fill(new.date)
`

Comment: Had to load Tidyr but that did it. Thanks! If you supply as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can copy `ref.date` into `new.date` column and then use `fill` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(new.date = ref.date) %>% tidyr::fill(new.date)

#  A   ref.date   new.date
#1 1       <NA>       <NA>
#2 2 2018-10-12 2018-10-12
#3 3       <NA> 2018-10-12
#4 4       <NA> 2018-10-12
#5 5 2019-12-15 2019-12-15
#6 6       <NA> 2019-12-15
#7 7       <NA> 2019-12-15
#8 8       <NA> 2019-12-15
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do it:

```r
df <- data.frame(A = c(1:8), ref.date = c(NA, "10/12/18", NA, NA, "12/15/19", NA, NA, NA))
df$ref.date <- as.Date(df$ref.date, format = "%m/%d/%y")
df$new.date <- NA

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(new.date = ref.date) %>% 
  fill(`new.date`, .direction = "down")
#>   A   ref.date   new.date
#> 1 1       <NA>       <NA>
#> 2 2 2018-10-12 2018-10-12
#> 3 3       <NA> 2018-10-12
#> 4 4       <NA> 2018-10-12
#> 5 5 2019-12-15 2019-12-15
#> 6 6       <NA> 2019-12-15
#> 7 7       <NA> 2019-12-15
#> 8 8       <NA> 2019-12-15
```

Comment: Oh, I see @Ronak Shah also thought of the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some base R solutions.

- using `rle()` + `cumsum()`:

```
df$new.date <- with(rle(cumsum(!is.na(df$ref.date))),
                    rep(df$ref.date[c(0,cumsum(lengths[-length(lengths)]))+1],lengths))
```

- using `split()` + `rbind()`:

```
df <- do.call(rbind,
              c(make.row.names = F,
                lapply(split(df,cumsum(!is.na(df$ref.date))), 
                       function(v) cbind(v,new.date = head(v$ref.date,1)))))
```

such that

```
> df
  A   ref.date   new.date
1 1       <NA>       <NA>
2 2 2018-10-12 2018-10-12
3 3       <NA> 2018-10-12
4 4       <NA> 2018-10-12
5 5 2019-12-15 2019-12-15
6 6       <NA> 2019-12-15
7 7       <NA> 2019-12-15
8 8       <NA> 2019-12-15
```

Comment: Nice to see the base R solution as well, thank you